# Java - library to generate source code changed e.g. by JavaScript from normal source code from browser?

Tags: java, html, browser, firebug

the view source browser feature shows the plain HTML as received by the browser. When I look at the same source code in Firefug. For example Firefox shows you the HTML code, while Firebug shows the rendered code. Is there any way to obtain rendered code from standard source code in Java? Some library?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify a little bit. Are you wanting to see the source of the Javascript on a webpage or a Java application you have in your browser?

Comment: The rendered code can change depending on what Javascript has been executed on the client at any point in time.  I.e. there's no such thing as _the_ rendered code, it can change based on user actions and even asynchronous events.

Comment: I need to convert HTML source code of String type (original source code as you can get in in firefox or every other browser by right mouse click and then "show source code") to HTML source code of String type as I see when I show webpage in Firebug... For example [this page](http://www.br.de/fernsehen/bayerisches-fernsehen/sendungen/abendschau/bayerwald-tierpark-livereportage-100.html)... there is <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"...</object> when I look at source in Firebug... and I need to acces to this element (<object>) when I download source. And I need it to convert in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to get rendered HTML, try to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net). It invokes most of the JavaScript events (onload, onclick, onsubmit...) automatically and allows you to act as "normal" browser:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.br.de/fernsehen/bayerisches-fernsehen/sendungen/abendschau/bayerwald-tierpark-livereportage-100.html");
DomNodeList<DomElement> objectList = page.getElementsByTagName("object");
```

Edited:

Isn't this the same as the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808354/java-convert-html-source-code-of-string-type-by-show-source-code-to-source?